# HTTP Status 404 on Struts project with tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to follow [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/struts-2/struts-2-helloworld-example/) tutorial about how getting started to Struts.
I followed the exact steps, but in the end I got this error `HTTP Status 404 - /Struts2-HelloWorldExample/`

I know 404 error means that I was able to communicate to the server, but server could not find what I requested. I suspected that there's something wrong with my library, but I couldn't find anything in the solution for the same problem.

[image]

My java code:

```
package com.aziz;

public class HelloWorldExample {

    private String name;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return "success";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
  <display-name>Struts 2 - Hello World Example</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
     <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
     <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
     </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

hello.jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello <s:property value="name"/>!
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World Example</h1>
    <form action="hello">
        <label for="name">Enter your name</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="hello"
                class="com.aziz.HelloWorldExample">
                <result name="success">hello.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

And I'm not sure what i'm doing is right or wrong but i just added manually struts library that i've downloaded from [here](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts251)(full distribution) in the WEB-INF/lib folder, so I have these JAR in that folder:

[image]

And the last thing, I have no error but these warning on my markers:

[image]

I already checked this error, Idk what's that mean because when I see the solution, someone say i need to decide whether and which of the libraries to copy to the WAR in project Properties -> Java EE Module Dependencies. But in my project properties there's no such thing as Java EE Module Dependencies.
I really need your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try by modifying this -> <welcome-file>/WebContent/index.jsp</welcome-file>

Comment: Don't include all jars from the full distribution. If you don't know what to include then download `Essential Dependencies Only` distribution.

Comment: You probably have wrong project configuration in Eclipse and wrong dependencies. Recreate a project with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have put the jsp files inside WEBCONTENT not in WEB-INF and try to put only  the libraries which I have given below.

commons-collections-3.1.jar,
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar,
commons-io-2.2.jar,
commons-lang-2.4.ja,r
commons-lang3-3.2.jar,
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar,
freemarker-2.3.22.jar,
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar,
ognl-3.0.13.jar,
struts2-core-2.3.28.jar,
xwork-core-2.3.28.jar,

Try this and try restarting the server and check it.Hope it works.

Regards,
Dhanya

Comment: Why do you think that it is wrong to put files in web-inf?

Comment: @AleksandrM:  don't have direct access to content inside WEB-INF folder so you will not be able to call your jsp file that is create inside WEB-INF folder.you just try to create your jsp files outside WEB-INF.

Comment: Why do you need direct access? Action -> JSP. Not other way around.